# Binding visibility to control in different class with WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, visibility

In my main window xaml I have two user controls and two `RadioButton`s.  I want the `RadioButton`s  to control the `Visibility` of the user controls.
xaml excerpt:

```
    <WpfApp2:ViewTree/>

    <WpfApp2:ViewTab/>

    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton_Tree" GroupName="View"
                 IsChecked="True"> Tree View </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton_Tab" GroupName="View"
                 IsChecked="False" >Tab View</RadioButton>
```

in the user controls, I have something like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, 
                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
                     ElementName=Window1.radioButton_Tree}" >
```

At run time I get this error:
`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Window1.radioButton_Tab'`

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name Window1 is not in the context of user control.

Can you use the code below?

```
<WpfApp2:ViewTree Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, 
                  Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
                  ElementName=radioButton_Tree}" />

<WpfApp2:ViewTab Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, 
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
                 ElementName=radioButton_Tab}" />

<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton_Tree" GroupName="View"
             IsChecked="True"> Tree View </RadioButton>

<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton_Tab" GroupName="View"
             IsChecked="False" >Tab View</RadioButton>
```